# Getting the biggest type from a variadic type list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, c++14

I'm trying to get the biggest type from a variadic template type list. I'm getting unexpected results:

```
// Bigger between two types
template<typename T1, typename T2> 
using Bigger = std::conditional_t<sizeof(T1) >= sizeof(T2), T1, T2>;

// Recursion helper
template<typename...> 
struct BiggestHelper;

// 2 or more types
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... TArgs> 
struct BiggestHelper<T1, T2, TArgs...>
{
    using Type = Bigger<T1, BiggestHelper<T2, TArgs...>>;
};

// Exactly 2 types
template<typename T1, typename T2> 
struct BiggestHelper<T1, T2>
{
    using Type = Bigger<T1, T2>;
};

// Exactly one type
template<typename T> 
struct BiggestHelper<T>
{
    using Type = T;
};

template<typename... TArgs> 
using Biggest = typename BiggestHelper<TArgs...>::Type;
```

Here's an example of the results:

```
sizeof(double) -> 8
sizeof(Biggest<int, char, long, std::string, long long, double>) -> 4
```

What am I doing wrong? I expect a number bigger than 4 to be returned.

Comment: ([testcase](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3a43d2f54533f76))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type should be the bigger of `T1` and the biggest of the remaining types, not the bigger of `T1` and `BiggestHelper</*...*/>` (which is an empty struct). Also, for the record, the biggest type in your list is almost certainly `std::string`, rather than `double`.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... TArgs> 
struct BiggestHelper<T1, T2, TArgs...>
{
    using Type = Bigger<T1, typename BiggestHelper<T2, TArgs...>::Type>;
                          //^^^^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd4b9d0ae38538af).

Comment: I feel so dumb! Thanks