# Can we use metaprograming get biggest(sizeof) type in a union?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I know [how to get the biggest type in typelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442859/getting-the-biggest-type-from-a-variadic-type-list/26442896#26442896)

Is there a way get biggest(sizeof) type in a union?

I mean Something like:

```
GetBiggestType<SomeUnionType>::type
```

and the type is biggest type.

Comment: Not unless you already know what all the types in the union are.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  you mean we can't do like this: GetBiggestType<SomeUnion>::type to get this type?

Comment: There is no way to do this in C++ without you specifying the types or members to check.

Comment: Not until static reflection comes. Funny enough, there is a roundabout way to do this for a POD struct.

Answer (score 0):

I would think in most cases the size of the union (which will be big enough to hold the largest member plus alignment padding) would be sufficient, that you would not actually need the type of that largest member.

And sizeof() will give you that, no need for metaprogramming.

Comment: Yes,you are right,but your answer does not match my question. I need type not size. You can modify answer just say no.I will set your anwser as best.Thanks.